# Connecting Postgresql running on GCE from app engine

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, jdbc, google-compute-engine

I've googled a lot but I couldn't find the answer. 
I'm building an application for android which backend is on Google AppEngine, but i need a geospatial database to use. I decide to use PostGIS, running on a Google compute engine instance. Now it's running on my own computer and visible from outside (tested). I could connect it from my local DEV app engine server (from another computer), but when I deploy my backend it couldn't.

I tied to use a simple DB connection.
Load the driver:

```
static{
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and build connection:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    if(mConnection == null || mConnection.isClosed()) {
        mConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "....", "....");
    }

    System.out.println("GIS Connection alive? "+ !mConnection.isClosed());

    return mConnection;
}
```

I'm using the postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc4.jar.

I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763090/connecting-to-postgresql-in-java-app-engine) where was some info about restrictions, but i can't believe there's no simple way connect to outer database. It would be nice if i could get around the socketing quotas.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

believe it. its not supported to use that protocol. use cloud sql or build an https-based service on your vm.